# Valid Visa on expired US passport - do I have to transfer the Visa?

Tags: visas

I recently renewed my passport. The expired one has an Indian visa that will be valid until 2017. Is it necessary for me to get the visa transferred to the renewed passport,  to travel to India?

Answer (score 0):

Just take both passports when you travel to India, no need to transfer the visa.  I had the same situation and had no issues visiting India.